# Linux Mint file-chooser: show filename-entry instead of path-bar?

Tags: linux-mint, gsettings

In Linux Mint 18.2, the default path selector looks like this:

[image: path bar]

I want it to look like this:

[image: filename-entry]

So I went opened up `dconf-editor` and changed `org.gtk.settings.filechooser location-mode` from `path-bar` to `filename-entry`. Unfortunately, this didn't have any effect, and when I opened up `dconf-editor` later, it had reverted back to `path bar`. So then I used `gsettings` to do it myself:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser location-mode filename-entry
```

I tried this both with and without sudo. After running the command, `gsettings get` said that it did indeed take effect and was now set to `filename-entry`. Excited, I opened up `gedit` to test this, but was dismayed to find it was still the path bar and not filename-entry. Perplexingly, after closing the file-chooser in `gedit`, `gsettings get` now showed that `location-mode` had reverted to `path-bar`.

After trying this a few times, I determined that closing the file-chooser causes the setting to revert.

How can I get the file-chooser to use the path bar?

Comment: Have you found out anything? I am having the exact same problem and it's bugging me :|

Comment: Bug report: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/938

Comment: The bug was dismissed by GNOME developers in typical "users shouldn't be able to configure their desktop" fashion.

Comment: This issue is also discussed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome3/+bug/1830979 and https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/2723

Answer (score 6):

Having the same issue. also Linux Mint 18.2.

A workaround is to press Ctrl-L to switch to Location-entry mode.

I would also like a method to make this permanent.

Comment: unfortunately this bug is more than 2 years old now (gtkfilechooser won't read value) but there is no interest in fixing it